# Update a column in Listbox that has multiple columns

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Access Form which contains a listbox (lstusers) with 7 columns in it (Row Source Type - value list)

I am able to enter the 1st row with a static heading in the list box. Also, I am able to import data in multiple rows with the command below:

me.lstusers.additem VariableA & ";" &  me.lstusers.additem VariableB 
and so on up to the 6th column. The 7th column will be updated later on the process the string "Checked".

So what I am trying to do is that once row 1 is done checking, Column 7 on row #1 should be updated with the string "Checked" 
Then row #2 on so on.

My Code is: 
lstUsers.Column(everify, i) = "Checked"

Variable "everify" has a static enum value of 8 and the "i" being an integer variable changes in the For loop
So it will be changed to  - lstUsers.Column(8, 1) = "Checked"

But I get error "Object Required"

Comment: Please post the actual code (not just separate snippets) and format it as code.

Comment: Code is updated

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-column-property-access

> You can use the Column property to refer to a specific column, or column and row combination, in a multiple-column combo box or list box. **Read-only** Variant.
>   (Emphasis mine)

So: you can read them, but you can't update the displayed values in listbox columns directly.
(That one gets an "Object required" error when trying is ... interesting.)

You'll have to rethink your approach.

Either update and re-assign the full value list string for every change.

Or use row source type "Table" and use a local table as data buffer, where you update the values, and then `lstUsers.Requery`.

My guess is that the latter would be cleaner code.